# How to store data extremely quickly

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, storage

I have to sample a sensor on a raspi at at rate of 1 million samples/second for around 30 seconds. Each sample is 6 characters How do I store this data without slowing down the program? I can save it in memory until after the sample time, or store it directly to the disk.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Store it in memory. Disk is slow.

Comment: Memory would be the fastest, but flushing to disk would make more sense... For example, use Prometheus, Redis, or InfluxDB...

Comment: If you want to write to disks short term, i'd suggest looking into the [feather format](https://dhirajkumarblog.medium.com/feather-vs-csv-file-format-e21f8509e772) as it might be helpful in what you're trying to do.

Comment: Start by writing an empty loop and time it, to figure out how much time you have available. Do the same for your different ways to store the data. Then use whichever is easiest and fits within your time budget. A 7200 RPM drive writes at least 80 MB/s, so 6MB/s shouldn't be a problem if you want to write to any disk-like device...

Comment: @rv.kvetch, Isn't Feather optimized to write tablar data? Enzo question does not seems to imply that the data is collected in a table (or anything of the kind).

Answer (score 1):

Not to slow down your Python program you can write to file asynchronously in a separate [threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) and use [queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) to exchange data with thread. Also writing large portions of data at a time to file will improve speed greatly.

I made a simple `Writer` class down below that does all above suggestions. After class there are few lines of code with example of usage. This example writes about 1 million samples within just 1 second.

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow70056372#main.py)

```py
class Writer:
    import threading, queue
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.fname = file_name
        self.buf = []
        self.q = self.queue.Queue(128)
        self.t = self.threading.Thread(
            target = self._FileWrite)
        self.t.start()
    def Finish(self):
        self.q.put(self.buf)
        self.buf = []
        self.q.put(None)
        self.t.join()
    def Write(self, obj):
        self.buf.append(obj)
        if len(self.buf) >= 50_000:
            self.q.put(self.buf)
            self.buf = []
    def _FileWrite(self):
        with open(self.fname, 'wb') as f:
            while True:
                buf = self.q.get()
                if buf is None:
                    break
                data = b''
                for e in buf:
                    data += e.encode('ascii')
                f.write(data)

# Example of usage

writer = Writer('out.bin')
for i in range(1_234_567):
    writer.Write('abcdef')
writer.Finish()

import os
print('Resulting file size:', os.path.getsize('out.bin'))
```

Output:

```
Resulting file size: 7407402
```